# Express the integral as beta function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

How can this definite integral be represented in the form of **$\beta$ function** ?

$ \int_0^1 \frac{x dx}{\sqrt{1-x^5}} $

The answer is **$\frac{1}{5}\beta (\frac{2}{5}, \frac{1}{2})$** but I am not sure how to reach here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the substitution $u= x^5$, $x = u^{1/5}$, $dx = (1/5)u^{-4/5}$.

Comment: Thanks @ncmathsadist